# LAMP web server file permissions

Tags: security, browser, permissions, webserver, chmod

I've got a LAMP webserver running my homepage (index.html in var/www/).  I'd like to know in general how to set my file permissions so that browsers can't access anything besides the html/php files I want to show.  Right now I've sort of accidentally chmodded everything to 777. I understand that .htaccess only protects the www folder and inwards... How can I set my permissions so that I have an svn folder that svn can still access but browsers can't?

Comment: This is not a programming question, this should be on serverfault.

Answer (score 1):

In security you should follow the paradigm of "Least Privilege Access".   It is best to do a `chmod 500 -R /var/www`  `chown www-data -R /var/www`.  This is assuming that your php code is running as www-data, you could run a `<?php system('whoami')?>` to verify your user account.

A chmod 500 gives the web root read and execute privileges.  Write privileges is very dangerous as this is vital for defacing your site.  The last number should **always** be zero,  this is global privileges and you don't want any other account/process accessing your webroot.